# equalent jquery/ajax implementation for curl

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, curl

I am looking for similar implementation in jquery/ajax for following curl statement,

curl -F 'method=get'      -F 'fields=posts'          -F 'access_token=CAACEdEose0cBADgsIKAv0SxeYkP1VsSjSd6lmEuqZA2nlChpi4bccf05mrKpS5HN8BpSBXAeSyhLrq10KMe1sXTLZBl1xzcWPwsvLCCBaPfHDC5JkLZCZCQtDpH4MVH4ZD'         https://graph.facebook.com/15354767

Comment: you should not post access tokens, and you should not use them directly on the client. also, your question is way too broad and does not show any research. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question and if you are not blocked by [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), this should be something like that :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/15354767",
    type: "GET",
    data: { 
        fields: "posts",
        access_token: "CAACEdEose0cBADgsIKAv0SxeYkP1VsSjSd6lmEuqZA2nlChpi4bccf05mrKpS5HN8BpSBXAeSyhLrq10KMe1sXTLZBl1xzcWPwsvLCCBaPfHDC5JkLZCZCQtDpH4MVH4ZD"
    }
});
```

I recommended you to use PHP instead of JS, to do that, because acces_token must be protected.